# "Yes" if a value partially matches in a range of values, blank otherwise

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of values (column A for this example) like such:

```
Phytophora sojae
Phytophora ramorum
Cryptococcus neoformans
Coccidioides posadasii
```

And I'd like to create a new formula column (B) that has the value "Yes" if the value in A is present in another column (C) that might look like:

```
Cryptococcus neoformans var. neoformans
Coccidioides posadasii C735 delta SOWgp
```

So that the spreadsheet will ultimately look like:

```
A                       | B   | C
Phytophora sojae        |     | Cryptococcus neoformans var. neoformans
Phytophora ramorum      |     | Coccidioides posadasii C735 delta SOWgp
Cryptococcus neoformans | Yes |
Coccidioides posadasii  | Yes |
```

I think I need a formula that uses some combination of FIND, FILTER, and IF; however, the FIND function does not seem to work as I expect it to.

If I can figure out how to partially match against a range, it might be sufficient, because I think I can use this [solution](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/eiqyl-oz7rc%5B1-25-false%5D) `B1 = IF(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A ; A:A=C1 ))) ; "Yes" ; "")` to map it to a Yes or blank value.

In Python, the equivalent operation might look like:

```
for i, query in enumerate(A):
    for target in C:
        if query in target:
            B[i] = "Yes"
            break
```

Comment: How does `A1=C1`?

Comment: Did my solution help you?

Comment: The elements of A are substrings of C, so that it partially matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should do the trick:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A:A;C:C;{1}*SIGN(ROW(A:A));0)=A:A;"Yes";"");""))`

Explained from the inside out:

- the `VLOOKUP` will lookup column A in column C
- the `IF` statement will result "Yes" if something has been found
- the `IFERROR` function will ignore empty cells
- the `ARRAYFORMULA` will take on complete column ranges

In your example, column B is completely empty. If you add `A1` to `C4` then `B1` will give "Yes".

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the reputation to vote you up.  I was looking for a partial match solution.  "Yes" if A_n is a substring of any row in C.  I think your solution is an exact matching solution.

Comment: I will revise the answer.

Comment: I'm working on a script to do the work for you.